# Bootstrap 5 maximum row height causing image to break out of container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to set a maximum height for a banner I am creating in `bootstrap5` like this..

```css
.banner {
    background: red;
    max-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 
    <div class="container d-flex banner">
        
            <div class="col-2">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-10">
                This is some text for the right hand side of the banner
            </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Why is the image breaking out of the banner? I was expecting it to resize itself proportionally because I am using `img-fluid`. Where am I going wrong>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img-fluid` only adds `max-width:100%` and `height:auto` since your content is restricted by height and not width you need to add `max-height:100%`

```css
.banner {
    background: red;
    max-height: 50px;
}
.img-fluid{
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 
    <div class="container d-flex banner">
        
            <div class="col-2">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-10">
                This is some text for the right hand side of the banner
            </div>

    </div>

</body>
```